# NPM Timeout on install while overseas

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm on vacation outside of the US where the connection is quite slow and `npm install` is giving me some trouble.

```
› npm config list
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.7.3 node/v5.8.0 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/lfender/.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; globalconfig /Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/etc/npmrc
strict-ssl = false

; node bin location = /Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/lfender/source/ag.js
; HOME = /Users/lfender
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

npm install --verbose
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.56.162:443
```

I have tried setting the registry to `http` but it looks as though it is still trying to connect on `443` or ssl.

It continues to do this and retries over and over again. What else can I try to establish communication with the registry?

Even when connecting to corporate VPN housed in the US it still fails.

```
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.56.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
```

I suspect its an issue with the ISP

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout? E.g., https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#fetch-retry-maxtimeout

Comment: its strange, even the page is timing out. when i visit other sites they load just fine

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar issue when on slow internet and on experimenting I found out that we can set the timeout value.
So, doing

`npm install -timeout=9999999`

works for me as it sets the timeout to 9999999 ms.

Answer (score 1):

*I know it is not a real solution but this workaround could help.*

After hours of struggling with the same problem, I had installed `yarn` and then installed the dependencies using `yarn`.

```sh
# 1: install yarn:
sudo npm install --global yarn

# 2: install packages from "package.json" with yarn:
yarn install
```

See also: ["Yarn usage"](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage).

`yarn` also faced a really bad internet connection, but successfully installed dependent packages (even though with warnings):

> `info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...`

It seems like `yarn` is more dogged.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by first listing my configurations of my npm

```
npm config ls -l
```

Look after https-proxy/http-proxy and possibly you will find a setting like "http://10.10.20.60:80/". If it is there do the following command

```
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Afterwards try installing again with

```
npm install -g <what u want to install>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using node version 17.3.0 when I had this problem. I updated to node version 17.4.0 and it worked. Try to update your node if all else fails.