# Error trying to install python3 with homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew

I'm trying to install python3 with homebrew.

I have ran

`brew install python3`

but I get the error

```
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask --origin=origin --template=` exited with 128
```

Does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: is your `homerew` installed properly? can you check it?

Comment: `brew update` ?

Comment: "brew update" and then "brew doctor" see if there are any errors output to be resolved.  If that fails, then take a look at this answer it might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878838/git-rpc-failed-curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: If you are downloading or installing then i think You have to use first *git clone* then script or shell name

Answer (score 1):

There is already a issue posted on GitHub about this.

```
brew uninstall git
brew update
brew install git
```

Should solve the problem if its git installation problem.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/82273