# Error, "error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining" when trying to push to git

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a project to a new Github repo but keep getting the error, `error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` after running, `git push`.

Due to the fact that the file size is quite much about 120MB, I suspected that could be the issue and increased the buffer size by using the command "git config --global http.postBuffer 11524288000" but I still keep getting the error.

Here is the complete log

```
C:\Users\OYERO HABIB\OneDrive\Documents>git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 7739, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7739/7739), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5804/5804), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7739/7739), 41.59 MiB | 51.93 MiB/s, done.
Total 7739 (delta 1632), reused 7739 (delta 1632), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Although your is a push, this is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60878838/1256452) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38618885/1256452) (or one of the many other questions that come up if you search for the string "RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining").

Comment: You [should not set `http.postBuffer` in normal usage](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer).  Unless something on your computer or network is completely broken, all it serves to do is waste memory (and in your case, a lot of memory).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using setting up ssh which worked just perfectly unlike the initial HTTPS I was using.