# UnrealEngine git pull failed

Tags: git, github

```
PS D:\> git clone  --depth 1 -b release https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git
Cloning into 'UnrealEngine'...
warning: git-credential-manager-core was renamed to git-credential-manager
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/rename for more information
remote: Enumerating objects: 159097, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (159097/159097), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123205/123205), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
PS D:\> git config --global http.postBuffer 2147483648
PS D:\> git config --global core.compression -1
PS D:\> git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0
PS D:\> git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999
```

I have set these up, but still failed.

I want to clone this repository, but it keeps failing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878838/git-rpc-failed-curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining

Comment: This answers your question https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/rename.md

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco i don't think so, that's only a warning and the error message doesn't match the one given in the article