# Error on installing node: npm ERR code ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, npm, server

I am trying to install npm in a particular directory on the office's laptop. But it is throwing an error:

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>
> npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>
> npm ERR! network request to 'company-url' failed, reason: connect
> ETIMEDOUT 10.82.13.225:4873
>
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad
> network settings.

My questions here are:

1. How can I fix the above errors?
2. In general, How can I check whether the proxy is set on my laptop or not?
3. I had searched about this issue and saw some suggestions to change the proxy settings. Will there be any conflict with the company's policies if I change them (as per the solutions that I found on google)?

Comment: your company network policy is not allowing to download files from those urls.

Comment: possibly duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830049/npm-timeout-on-install-while-overseas

Comment: The last time I had a problem like this was because of my company VPN, do you have a VPN running?

Answer (score 3):

Disable ipv6 work on my case. Instruction on Windows: https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=17573